# How to get Shopify order data to product page

Tags: javascript, html, web, shopify, liquid

I am trying to build a Map that marks the cities where the order has been made from to customers.

I have pasted a js based map to the page.liquid file.

Now i need to somehow retrieve the data of orders and obtain the cities and use it place markers on my map.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain a little more what you mean? If you are trying to obtain data from a list, use JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for an App Proxy. You create a private App that can access all your orders, and assign a location to a product ID. Use the proxy in your front-end code to securely call the back end with the product ID that is interesting to you. Your backend simply returns the coordinates of orders that match, as you built out that small optimization in your App. Now your front-end map gets good data to draw, and you're done.